# Solving a differential equation using $F=ma$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

> A  body with mass $m = \frac{1}{2}$ = kilogram $\left(kg\right)$ is attached to the end of a spring that is stretched two meters by a force of $100$ Newtons. It is set in motion with an initial position of $y_0=\frac{1}{2}$$\left(m\right)$ and velocity of $v_0=\frac{1}{2}$$\left(\frac{m}{s}\right)$. Find the position function of the body as well as the amplitude, frequency, period of oscillation, and time lag of the motion.

So I organized the information that I know:

$m=\frac{1}{2}kg$

$F=100N$

$y_0=\frac{1}{2}m$

$v_0=\frac{1}{2}\frac{m}{s}$

So $\frac{F}{m}=a \Rightarrow\frac{100N}{\frac{1}{2}kg} = 200\frac{m}{s^2}$

So now I have my $F=ma$ and I assume from here I integrate my acceleration to get my velocity function and then integrate my velocity function to get my position function?

Integrating my $a(t)$ I get:

$\int\frac{200m}{s^2}dt = \frac{200m}{s}+C_1$

And then integrating this again:

$\int\frac{200m}{s}+C_1dt = 200m+C_1t+C_2$

Is this correct?  If so how do I find the amplitude, frequency, period of oscillation, and time lag from here?

Comment: It seems to me you made some mistakes in sign and omitted parentheses.  Have a look at your integration steps again, please.

Comment: @hardmath just looked through my steps again and having a hard time locating sign errors

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding the setup, but at least the integration seems off. You are assuming that the acceleration $a$ is not a function of time. This gives you no oscillations what so ever.

From what I remember, these problems always made use of hooks laws ($F = k\Delta x$) where $\Delta x$ is the displacement from the equilibrium. 
If you know the force $F = 100 N$ at displacement $\Delta x = 2m$, then you can determine the constant $k$, and get another expression for the accelleration $$F = - k \Delta x = m a \rightarrow  a = a(t) = - \frac{k\Delta x(t)}{m}$$

Does this sound familiar?

If your still stuck, write the equation as:
$$ a(t) = -\frac{k\Delta x(t)}{m} ~ \rightarrow ~~ x'' + \frac{k}{m}x = 0 $$
which has a periodic solution, since $k, m > 0 $.